# k8s: Error pulling images from ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, kubelet, nsenter

We constantly get `Waiting: ImagePullBackOff` during CI upgrades. Anybody know whats happening? k8s cluster 1.6.2 installed via kops. During upgrades, we do `kubectl set image` and during the last 2 days, we are seeing the following error

`Failed to pull image "********.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/backend:da76bb49ec9a": rpc error: code = 2 desc = net/http: request canceled
Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "backend" with ErrImagePull: "rpc error: code = 2 desc = net/http: request canceled"`

journalctl -r -u kubelet

`Jul 26 09:32:40 ip-10-0-49-227 kubelet[840]: W0726 09:32:40.731903     840 docker_sandbox.go:263] NetworkPlugin kubenet failed on the status hook for pod "backend-1277054742-bb8zm_default": Unexpected command output nsenter: cannot open : No such file or directory
Jul 26 09:32:40 ip-10-0-49-227 kubelet[840]: E0726 09:32:40.724387     840 generic.go:239] PLEG: Ignoring events for pod frontend-1493767179-84rkl/default: rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error: No such container: 2421109e0d1eb31242c5088b547c0f29377816ca068a283b8fe6c2d8e7e5874d
Jul 26 09:32:40 ip-10-0-49-227 kubelet[840]: E0726 09:32:40.724371     840 kuberuntime_manager.go:858] getPodContainerStatuses for pod "frontend-1493767179-84rkl_default(0fff3b22-71c8-11e7-9679-02c1112ca4ec)" failed: rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error: No such container: 2421109e0d1eb31242c5088b547c0f29377816ca068a283b8fe6c2d8e7e5874d
Jul 26 09:32:40 ip-10-0-49-227 kubelet[840]: E0726 09:32:40.724358     840 kuberuntime_container.go:385] ContainerStatus for 2421109e0d1eb31242c5088b547c0f29377816ca068a283b8fe6c2d8e7e5874d error: rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error: No such container: 2421109e0d1eb31242c5088b547c0f29377816ca068a283b8fe6c2d8e7e5874d
Jul 26 09:32:40 ip-10-0-49-227 kubelet[840]: E0726 09:32:40.724329     840 remote_runtime.go:269] ContainerStatus "2421109e0d1eb31242c5088b547c0f29377816ca068a283b8fe6c2d8e7e5874d" from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error: No such container: 2421109e0d1eb31242c5088b547c0f29377816ca068a283b8fe6c2d8e7e5874d
Jul 26 09:32:40 ip-10-0-49-227 kubelet[840]: with error: exit status 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try running `kubectl create configmap -n kube-system kube-dns`

For more context, check out known issues with kubernetes 1.6 https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/releases/tag/1.6.0

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by a known [docker bug](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/23184) where shutdown occurs before the content is synced to disk on layer creation. The fix is included in docker v1.13.

work around is to remove the empty files and re-pull the image.